# How to deal with "iTunes Store operation failed" error?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have gotten this error (screenshot below) a couple of times now when trying to upload an archive of an iPhone app to the App Store for TestFlight purposes.

The Apple Developer account is definitely paid for and I've clicked the "Download All" button to get a hold of all the provisioning profiles from Apple.

Any ideas?

[image: itunes error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As is the case with a lot of these questions about Xcode the fix was simple. After a `Clean Build Folder` (Alt+Shift+Cmd+K), another `Archive`, and unticking the bitcode checkbox on the app upload screen, everything worked fine.